# How to prove whether $x^{2}+y^{2}+1$ is irreducible over $\mathbb{C}$ or not?

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, irreducible-polynomials

Let's consider a 2-variable polynomial $f(x, y)= x^{2}+y^{2}+1$. It can be established that it's irreducible over $\mathbb{R}$.

For example, if it's irreducible over $\mathbb{R}$ as a polynomial of two variables, then if we assume $y=1$ the polynomial must be irreducible too, whereas $x^{2}+2$ doesn't look so (By the Eisenstein's criterion, for example).

The situation becomes slightly more interesting over $\mathbb{C}$. How to prove, in particular, that the $x^{2}+y^{2}+1$ is irreducible over $\mathbb{C}$ or not and which technique may be applied in order to cope with such kind of problems in  general cases?

Any piece of advice would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider the ring $R=\mathbb{C}[x]$, which is a PID. The polynomial $y^2+(x+i)(x-i)$ is irreducible in $R[y]$ by Eisenstein's criterion, as $x+i$ is irreducible in $R$ and $x-i$ doesn't divide $x+i$.

Note that Eisenstein's criterion applies to any PID, with the same proof as in the case for integers.